# When Kafka Event Expired, will the related consumer's Lag get stuck?

Tags: apache-kafka

Assume no more Kafka events are published in, when all the previous kafka events persisted in Kafka broker get expired due to retention and the related consumer has not completed consuming all event, Will the related Kafka consumer Lag get stuck with given partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow will be something like this:

1. Say your current offset is 100, but due to retention policy the earliest available offset is 110.
2. Your consumer sends a [FetchRequest](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchRequest) requesting messages from offset 100.
3. Kafka returns an error (`OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE` to be precise).
4. Your consumer reacts to this error by sending an [OffsetRequest](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetRequest) specifying which value it would like to reset to, lets say in your case it's `EARLIEST`.
5. Kafka returns an [OffsetResponse](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetResponse) with available offset, 110 in your case.
6. Your consumer forcibly sets current offset to 110 and starts fetching again.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. One thing I need to confirm is that If I use high level API, does the above offset reset flow is transparent for customer & can not be controlled by end user?

Comment: BTW, I'm use old consumer with high level API.

Comment: @BrianLing this applies to both old and new high level consumer. I'm not quite clear with your first question, but from what I understood - this process is not controlled by end user and happens automatically and under the hood. End user might not even know offset has been reset.

Answer (score 0):

looked though the code: (kafka 0.9 consumer)
there is resetStrategy defined when new consumer is created

```
public enum OffsetResetStrategy {
    LATEST, EARLIEST, NONE
}
```

so, if offset out of range, than consmer continue reading accoding to that policy